# I am trying to delete a particular record from the table in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

My view page code is

```
  @foreach($clients as $client)
<tr>
<td>{{ $client->client_id }}</td>

<td>{{ $client->ip_address }}</td>

<td>{{ $client->netmask }}</td>
<td>
    <a href= "del/{{$client->id}}"><button type = "button" class = "btn btn-danger ">
     Delete
  </button> 
</td>

</tr>

    @endforeach
```

My controller code for destroy method is :

```
public function destroy($id)

{

    $clients = Subnet_behind_client::findOrFail( $id );
    $clients->delete();
    return view('view2',compact('clients'));

}
```

My route file is:

```
Route::get('del/{id}', 'Subnet_Behind_ClientController@destroy');
```

I am able to view the records in a table in my view page but I am unable to delete a record from that table.

Comment: So you are not getting any error while deleting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good to me.

By the way, if you are deleting a record using its primary key then you can use **destroy()**

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#deleting-models

```
Subnet_behind_client::destroy( $id );
```

This way you don't need to fetch the record you want to delete. It will optimize the performance a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call `delete()` method onto a collection of records returned from `findOrFail()` method.

By doing this you can't access the query builder as now you have an `Collection` instead of a `QueryBuilder`.

To make it work, you can do it like this:

```
$clients = Subnet_behind_client::findOrFail( $id )->delete();
return view('view2',compact('clients'));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use this way:

First of all print the data if exist or check for existing entry.

```
$clients = Subnet_behind_client::where('id', $id)->get();
// dd($clients);
if(count($clients)>0){
    Subnet_behind_client::where('id', $id)->delete();
}
```

I think this trick will help you.

Make sure also if you forgot to mention define top of the controller:

```
use App\Subnet_behind_client;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Subnet_behind_client::destroy( $id );
```

And for deleting, I would suggest to use `DELETE` request instead of `GET`.